# Extreme case bounds on Diophantine approximation

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, diophantine-approximation

I am interested whether there are functions $\hat{b}(q)$ and $\check{b}(q)$ such that for any $\alpha\in [0,1)\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ we have for only finitely many $q's$

$$ \check{b}(q) \leq \Big\vert \alpha-\frac{p}{q} \Big\vert \quad \text{and} \quad \Big\vert \alpha-\frac{p}{q} \Big\vert \leq \hat{b}(q) \quad \text{for some}\;\; p\in \mathbb{Z}. $$

In a sense, I am wondering about the possible best case approximation and worst case approximation of irrational numbers.
Looking at the [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Upper_bounds_for_Diophantine_approximations) entry on Wikipedia, it seems as though if such functions exist then

$$ \check{b}(q)=O\Big( \frac{1}{q} \Big) \quad \text{and} \quad \hat{b}(q)=o\Big(\frac{1}{q^n}\Big) \;\; \text{for all} \;\; n\in \mathbb{N}. $$

Are there more explicit asymptotic bounds ? Can we say something like $\hat{b}(q)=o(e^{-q})$ and $\frac{\check{b}(q)}{q^{1+\epsilon}} \overset{q\to \infty}{\to} \infty$  for every $\epsilon>0$?

I assume something like this is known and I have not found this in a short search online. I am unused to these notions so I apologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: Question has since been [asked in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/454798/15780). See also [Exponentially well-approximable numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/395313/15780).